# Need to open MS Access extension 'accde'

Tags: ms-access

I have an MS Access file with the extension 'accde' and I need to open the tables in that database file.  I cannot use MS Access because mine is 64 and it says the file is 32.

At this point I need to extract the tables from the database and be able to open them anywhere else, it can be Excel, SAS or any other method.  Any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: Create a new database. From this, using "External Data", _import_ or _link_ the tables from the accde.

Comment: @Gustav, Access 64-bit can link/import Access 32-bit?

Comment: @June7: Data (tables) in a database file carries no bitness.

Comment: answer is yes, you can import tables from a accDE, regardless of what version (bit size) it was created with.